# GatsbyJS - Forward Slashes or numbers after Hash in URL crashes App

Tags: url, hash, crash, gatsby, slash

The URL of my app can be something like [www.example.com/#/c/2/v/1](http://www.example.com/#/c/2/v/1)

Yet the slashes and numbers after # are causing my GatsbyJS generated pages to crash.

The error message is: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#/c/2/v/1' is not a valid selector.

The parameters after hash are not to scroll, put to provide parameters to the app.

I've been struggling with this for two days.
Please Help.